# Laravel returns zero for the primary key value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having a problem in this laravel insertion code.  Whenever a new company is created, I get the output as Company created but with company_name as 0. I don't know why this happens. My code is

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $Company = new Company([
            'company_name' => $request->input('company_name'),
            'head'=>$request->input('head'),
            'Email'=>$request->input('email'),
            'address'=>$request->input('address'),
            'phno'=>$request->input('phno'),
            'contact_person'=>$request->input('contact_person')

        ]);
        if ($Company->save()) {

            $response = [
                'msg' => 'Company Created',
                'Company' => $Company
            ];
            return response()->json($response, 201);
        }
        $response = [
            'msg' => 'An Error Occurred',
        ];
        return response()->json($response, 502);
    }
```

My Model code is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'companies';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'company_name';
    protected $fillable = ['company_name','head','contact_person','phno','email','address'];

}
```

Input:

```
{
    "company_name":"cachii1",
    "head":"sankar",
    "email":"sankar@gmail.com",
    "address":"chennai",
    "phno":"123",
    "contact_person":"sankar"
}
```

output:

```
{
    "msg": "Company Created",
    "Company": {
        "company_name": 0,
        "head": "sankar",
        "address": "chennai",
        "phno": "123",
        "contact_person": "sankar"
    }
}
```

The Database Schema is
The Database Schema is
The Database Schema is

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
           // $table->increments('company_id');
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->primary('company_name');
            $table->string('head');
            $table->string('contact_person');
            $table->bigInteger('phno');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->text('address');

        });
```

Comment: did you try to dd($request->all())?

Comment: Show us your database structure / migration. I'd bet `company_name` is an integer field, not a string.

Comment: @ceejayoz I gave company_name as string in the database structure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, Laravel expects your model primary key to be auto incrementing. From what you've posted, it looks like that's not the case with your example.

Add this to your model definition:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```